# blpapi override is requested but not represented in outputted value?

Tags: blpapi

I am requesting the field TRADING_DAY_START_TIME_EOD (Market Open time).

In excel I can give overrides so I am doing the same for blpapi. The request is:

```
    securities[] = {
        "/sedol1/<SEDOL> AU Equity"
    }
    fields[] = {
        "TRADING_DAY_START_TIME_EOD"
    }
    overrides[] = {
        overrides = {
            fieldId = "SINGLE_DATE_OVERRIDE"
            value = "2020-03-30"
        }
    }
}
```

even if I use a ridiculous value for the override e.g. "HELLO", it does not complain and still provides me with a solution. Any ideas why the override is not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to format your date differently, like `20200330`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried 20200330 and as a datetime object. Still the request does not seem to be taking into account the override. It is odd that if I make the date a word such as "HELLO" it does not complain of invalid vlaue as you see for some other overrides, making me think there is no date type validation on this override.

Comment: Maybe worth asking HELP HELP on a terminal.

Comment: I have but they don't support blpapi.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Boomberg API to be honest.